# Fixing search form to pull keywords, not id value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been doing the railscast 111 advanced search form. I should be able to enter keywords that would be found on users profiles, such as "no kids, asian" and it should then display users who has no kids, asian on their profiles. If I type in "asian" in the search form I get the following error "Couldn't find Search with id=asian".

I believe I know where the confusion is coming from. In the advanced search form I have it so that it pulls data based on id, for example each ethnicity is assign a value 1-10 (1 being Asian since it's first selection). Same applies for other options such as education, gender, etc. However for the basic search form that is found on the index page, it should not try to pull from "ids". It instead should just allow me to do a full text search based on the information from the users database (contains all their profile information).

The error points to line in the searches controller:

```
  def index
  @search = Search.find(params[:search])
```

I have seriously been trying to tackle this for a very long time and I can't wrap my head around it. I have tried so many different solutions and I just can't seem to get it right. If anyone can help point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated!

searches controller:

```
  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.new(params[:search])
    if @search.save
      redirect_to @search
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @users = @search.users
    end

    def index
       @search = Search.find(params[:search])
     end

end
```

search model:

```
def users
    @users ||= find_users
  end

    private

  def find_users
    users = User.order(:id)
    users = users.where(gender: gender) if gender.present?
       users = users.where(zip_code: zip_code) if zip_code.present?
       users = users.where(children: children) if children.present?
       users = users.where(religion: religion) if religion.present?
       users = users.where(ethnicity: ethnicity) if ethnicity.present?
       users
  end
end
```

new.html (the index page search form is on):

```
<%= form_tag searches_path, method: :get do %>
<p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= button_tag "Search", name: nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answered the question yourself: you need a full text search. Commonly used for this purpose are https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx, http://sunspot.github.io, http://pickyrb.com or http://tenderlove.github.io/texticle (if you use postgres).

Hope this helps.